# Unable to build llvm on cygwin

Tags: build, cygwin, llvm

I am currently trying to build llvm 3.3 on Windows through Cygwin.

The compilation is going fine, but the build crashes during linking with this error:

```
llvm[2]: ======= Finished Linking Release+Asserts Executable llvm-mc (without symbols)
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Jupotter/Code/llvm-3.3.src/build/tools/llvm-mc'
llvm[2]: Compiling ExecutionDriver.cpp for Release+Asserts build
/cygdrive/c/Users/Jupotter/Code/llvm-3.3.src/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMMCJIT.a(SectionMemoryManager.o):SectionMemoryManager.cpp:(.text+0x3b): référence indéfinie vers « __register_frame »
/cygdrive/c/Users/Jupotter/Code/llvm-3.3.src/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMMCJIT.a(SectionMemoryManager.o):SectionMemoryManager.cpp:(.text+0x3b): relocalisation tronquée pour concorder avec la taille: R_X86_64_PC32 vers le symbole indéfini __register_frame
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/Jupotter/Code/llvm-3.3.src/build/Release+Asserts/lib/libLLVMMCJIT.a(SectionMemoryManager.o): mauvaise adresse de relocalisation 0x0 dans la section «.pdata»
```

In English:

```
undefined reference to "__register_frame
relocation truncated to concord with size: R_X*^_^$_PC32 to undefined symbol __register_frame
wrong relocation address in 0x0 in section ".pdata"
```

I build llvm with these commands:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure LDFLAGS=-Wl,--stack,16777216 --disable-jit --enable-targets=host-only
$ make -j4
```

The `LDFLAGS` options come from llvm [getting started guide](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#hardware) for win64 platform. I tried disabling jit since it seem to be libLLVMCJIT where there is a problem.

Any idea what could cause this build to fail?

Comment: See also http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2013-July/064332.html

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same error when compiling llvm on Cygwin(x86_64). But I can compile it on Cygwin(x86) successfully.

Answer (score 0):

External function `__register_frame` is part of `libgcc` or other compiler library but only for x86. It looks like you have compiled some code in 32-bit mode or used 32-bit library.